# Visual Studio Setup wizard with framework

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I have create a application that uses the .Net framework 4. I have created a installer with the setup wizard, but when i run the installer it wants to install .Net 4 client . If i try to start the application it says this application needs .Net Framework, version 4.

Anyone knows how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no magical way around this.
download the .net framework http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17851
 and add it to your project. set its installation to run before the installation of your program.